# Prepared statement fails but statement works on it's own with multiple WHERE parameters

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, where-clause

I have a procedure I'm writing that is failing once I try to make it dynamic with a prepared statement. The statement included in the string that is prepared does work on it's own outside of the prepared syntax.

Additional Information:

- The period_start() and period_end() functions return a date that is formatted and confirmed to work
- The procedure runs when any of the WHERE clause parameters are isolated to just themselves, even in the prepared statement string
- The string passed to the prepare stmt can run on it's own outside of being prepared

Objective: Get the prepared statement to execute with multiple AND declarations in the WHERE clause.

Current code:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS count_sessions_in_period;

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `count_sessions_in_period` (IN period INT)
BEGIN

SET @prepare_stmt = CONCAT("INSERT INTO 2017_p",period," (total_sessions,user_id,employee_name,manager_id)
SELECT @total_in_period := COUNT(DISTINCT m_s.class_id), m_u.uid, m_am.employee_name, m_u.manager_id
FROM m.sessions m_s
INNER JOIN m.assigned_employee m_am
ON m_s.sid = m_am.sid
INNER JOIN m.users m_u
ON m_am.employee_email = m_u.email
WHERE m_s.type = 'SESSIONS' AND m_s.date BETWEEN period_start(",period,") AND period_end(",period,") AND attended_status NOT LIKE '%cancelled%' AND attended_status NOT LIKE '%alert%'
GROUP BY m_u.uid
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE total_sessions=@total_in_period");

PREPARE stmt FROM @prepare_stmt;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END //
DELIMITER ;

#######################################################################

CALL count_sessions_in_period(1);
```

The error received is, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to us near "%alert%' at line 8"

Keep in mind that I have tried escaping all the quotes and making them all single or double.

Comment: Maybe it is too early for me but, I don't see any parameters or reason for this query to even be prepared/dynamic. ...and according to Notepad++, your query has a length of 553 (including whitespace/newlines)!

Comment: There is no reason for the prepared in this example initially. I simplified it, but I can add in the complication, but I added in the CONCAT() for demonstration purposes. It's really not relevant to the question though.

Comment: Ah, and I see the length doesn't matter, the declare of the similarly named variable threw me off.  What exactly do you mean by "failing"? Is it giving an error, or is it just the data is not updating as you expect it to?

Comment: If you get an errormessage, please always add the errormessage. My first guess: ansi mode. Try to use `'` instead of `"`.

Comment: The error message varies a bit; I'll add it though. It seemed to point to an issue with the quotes, so I tried it both ways. I escaped all of them and used single quotes, but keep in mind that the query runs if you just eliminate every AND and just use a single WHERE qualifier.

Comment: Please make sure you are copy & pasting 1:1 both your code and your error message as it is used, and not retype it from what you think is written there or as you copy it by reading it on your screen. You might be using two `'` instead of one `"` somewhere in `period_start(",period,") AND period_end(",period,")`, but we cannot figure this out for you if you are writing `"` here because you think it is a `"`, but it's really a `''`.

Comment: I've tried both of the variations you are describing, but the code is actually using double quotes. To clarify, the single quotes are around the stuff nested in the double quotes. It is exactly as you see here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was never answered, but in the end I found that when using dynamic prepared statements in MYSQL the amount of time for the SELECT to return a result negatively impacted the success of the INSERT.

In order to resolve this create a temporary table of your SELECT results and perform your INSERT...SELECT from the results in the temporary table. The issue stems from the asynchrony of INSERT...SELECT.